# Turn Outlook VBA into a standalone script

Tags: vba, windows, outlook, contacts

I've written some VBA which accesses the users Outlook notes and contacts, performs some manipulations, modifies the notes and contacts and at the same time outputs some text files. It works very well.

At present it runs (like all other VBA code) inside Outlook by doing **Tools > Macro > Macros...** however installation is a pain for non-tech savvy users to do and given that is is a simple BAS module (no forms), it doesn't really need to be run in this way.

A script file which could be executed by double-clicking within explorer would be a far better option. This would be easier to re-distribute and mean that anyone could use it.

Assuming it is possible to turn the VBA into a standalone script...

1. How do I do it?
2. What should I also know? Any caveats or things to be aware of? Any code I'll need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: You can run VBScript against Outlook with very few changes from VBA, but even encoded ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=E7877F67-C447-4873-B1B0-21F0626A6329&displaylang=en ) it is not really hidden from the user. VB.Net is, I believe, more secure, but requires a little more in the way of changes.

Comment: Maybe it would be easiest to just write an installer?

Comment: The fact that the code is viewable by the end user by opening up in a text editor isn't an issue. I would like to avoid having to provide step-by-step instructions on how to open Outlook, open the Visual Basic editor, import the files, close the editor, change the security settings and then run the script. Far easier just to give them a file and say "double click on this".

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is old, but is a VB6 COM DLL an option?

Here's a simple example of what you can do:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316983

And you can use an installer like Inno Setup to create an EXE which would install and register the DLL on each computer.